# Problem about M-matrix

Tags: matrices

Is a symmetric M-matrix positive definite? I intuitively think this is not correct. Can someone prove this or provide a counter-exmaple? I really appreciate it.

Comment: M-matrix guarantees the matrix is nonsingular. So the matrix you consider is not valid.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I didn't see the $M-$ condition at first.

Comment: can you provide a prove without appealing to the Z-matrix? I have no idea about that. Thanks

Comment: Please see, the **Added** section of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a $n × n$ real $Z-$matrix, then $A$ is a nonsingular $M$-matrix if and only if:
All the principal minors of $A$ are positive.

If in addition, you know that $A$ is symmetric, then this gives that $A$ is positive definite. So in particular, we have:

A symmetric $M-$matrix over the reals is positive definite
**Added**
By definition an $M$-matrix is a $Z$-matrix with eigenvalues whose real parts are all positive. If in addition, you know that the matrix is symmetric, then all of its eigenvalues are real. Therefore, a symmetric $M-$matrix has positive real eigenvalues. This shows that a symmetric $M-$matrix is positive definite. **Note a hermitian matrix is positive definite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are positive**. The proof of which can be found at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_definite_matrix